# Transfer user permissions

Tags: 2010, development, permissions

I have a `SPListItem` for which I need to transfer all directly given permissions from `Alice` to `Bob`. It sounds like a common scenario, but still I was not able to find a solution (except third party tools).

The closest I got is using `SPSecurableObject.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo` method to retrieve object permissions for `Alice`:

```
SPListItem item = getListItem(); 

var pi = item.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo(@"domain\alice");

foreach (SPRoleAssignment ra in pi.RoleAssignments)
{
    foreach (SPRoleDefinition rd in ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", rd.Name);
    }
}
```

However, this is suboptimal, since I am actually not interested in "effective" permissions. With code snippet above, permissions given thru groups are also listed. I need to find a way how to filter out only directly given permissions, I would expect a separate method for that, but I haven't found anything. Am I just blind?

Comment: So you are assigning users permissions directly and not defining groups? An easier way would of been to create groups and just work with groups. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Agreed, but this is how it was implemented. Now I need to replace an employee who is leaving the company with a new joiner, no time for major redesign. There are thousands of documents with unique permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michal,

You can do like:

```
 SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection reqRoleDef;
 foreach (SPRoleAssignment assign in itemRecomm.RoleAssignments)
 {
     if (assign.Member is SPUser)
     {
         SPUser user = assign.Member as SPUser;
         if (user.LoginName == @"Domain\alice")
         {
             reqRoleDef = assign.RoleDefinitionBindings;
             break;
         }
      }
 }
```

Or even in your code snippet, check what does `RoleAssignment.Member` returns? Is it a SPGroup or SPUser, if it return SPGroup for group permissions then you can simply ignore SPGroup one's and take SPUser Role Bindings!

I hope this helps

Comment: This looks promising, I will check it later today and will let you know (accept your answer). Thank you very much!